# MsSql secondary database synchronisation to Online Master MsSql database

Tags: sql-server, import

I have application that is talking to a Offline (local) database that is a replica of a (Online in-house db). The app is using this (local) database to keep new data that is being inputed when the employee travels to external location like a offshore platform with no network access.

The same application is running for other employees against a inn-house Online MsSql database. There is high volume of changes and addition beeing done everyday on the inn-house db, but only new additions to the Offline database.

Is there any tooling that can help me import the data from the offline database to the online live database when he gets back onshore? I can see a lot of issues here because of pk and fk suddenly being duplikat for different data in the same tables in these two databases?

Comment: I'd say the question is probably too big for a Q/A site like this. Maybe try another question the focuses on a specific problem you are having in doing this.

Comment: Using Guid's for keys should prevent duplicate key clashes. Beyond that we don't really have enough information to give you valuable feedback.

Comment: @JamesAnderson If i need to develop a solution or change the schema i woldent be asking this question here. I am only asking if anyone know of 3 party solution to merge changes between a online and a offline(sometimes online) database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like exactly what Merge Replication was designed for...occasionally connected subscribers.  Broad answer to a broad question :)

Comment: thank for pointing me in this direction,, it might be what im looking for.

Comment: @Darkmage , any luck finding a solution that works for you?

Comment: Merge Replication was the solution i went for, it does exactly what i was after. I have now a solution with a offline local MsSql database that i sync changes from and too the main Database when technician is back online. @Kevin3NF

Comment: @Darkmage glad to hear it :)